# Convergence in probability monotonicity property

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_n\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}X$ and $Y_n\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}Y$ and $Pr(X_n\leq Y_n)=1$ for all $n$. Is it true and how would one show that $X\leq Y$?

Edit: I mean that $Pr(X\leq Y)$.

This is what I've got so far: Let $X_n=X+\epsilon_n$ and $Y_n=Y+\delta_n$, where $\epsilon_n\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}0$ and $\delta_n \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} 0$. Then $X_n\leq Y_n \Leftrightarrow X+\epsilon_n \leq Y+\delta_n \Leftrightarrow X-Y\leq \delta_n -\epsilon_n$. Now $\delta_n -\epsilon_n\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}0$...but now I am stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by $X \leq Y$? Is it $\forall \omega \in \Omega.\ X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)$ or $\mathbb{E}X \leq \mathbb{E}Y$ or maybe $P(X \leq Y) = 1$ or even something else?

Comment: What does X n → p X  mean?

Comment: @oks It's [convergence in probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability), that is, $\forall \varepsilon > 0.\ \lim_n P(|X_n-X|\geq \varepsilon) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

...Continuing on your try (and kudos for having included it in your question), you know that $Z\leqslant Z_n$ almost surely and that $Z_n\to0$ in probability (with $Z=X-Y$ and $Z_n=\delta_n-\varepsilon_n$).

In particular, for every $z\gt0$, $\mathbb P(Z_n\gt z)\to0$. But $[Z\gt z]\subseteq[Z_n\gt z]$, hence, for every $n$, $\mathbb P(Z\gt z)\leqslant\mathbb P(Z_n\gt z)$, which implies $\mathbb P(Z\gt z)=0$. This holds for every $z\gt0$ hence $\mathbb P(Z\leqslant0)=1$, QED.

Comment: but isn't the definition of convergence in probability means that: for all $z>0, \mathbb{P}(|Z_{n}|>z)\rightarrow 0$? Applying your argument implies $\mathbb{P}(|Z|\leq 0)=1$, so it's saying the distance between X and Y must be 0 $\implies X=Y$?

Comment: No, applying the argument does not lead to what you say. Write it down as precisely as you can and you will see that the situation is not symmetric between $Z\gt z$ ($z\gt0$, what I did) and $Z\lt z$ ($z\lt0$, what you suggest to do, which fails). Can you state the reason why?